# How to process a photo for pygame?

Tags: image-processing, pygame

Hello everyone I am a beginner programmer in pygame. In my project, there are several png photos of the character for animation, but when I run the program, a white background appears along with the character.I cropped the white background in photoshop, but it didn't help. I downloaded models from another project and everything worked, but this is not the texture that I need. I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: It's very hard to help and tell you what's wrong with your code or images without being able to see either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is to change the background to transparent using an "alpha channel".  (I don't know what this term is in Photoshop.)  Save the image as a Portable Network Graphic file `.PNG`.

Pygame will directly load this image and preserve the background transparency during blits.

```
sprite_image1 = pygame.image.load("walk_frame1.png").convert_alpha()
```

There is also another method, using the `Surface.set_colorkey()` [function](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey).  Using this, the code would choose white as the key, making that part transparent:

```
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255 )
sprite_image1 = pygame.image.load("walk_frame1.png").convert()
sprite_image1.set_colorkey( WHITE )
```

The colour must match the specified key *exactly*, it would not match very-light grey for example ( say 254, 255, 255 ).